# What is the etymology of "eh" in "Ich habe eh nichts zu machen"?

Tags: etymology, adverb

My question is straightforward:

1. What is the etymology of *eh*?
2. Could *eh* in *Ich habe eh nichts zu machen* be an abbreviation for *eher*?

---

(I spelled *eh* with an **h** because the **e** seems to be pronounced longer, more like [eˑ])

Comment: Ich habe eh nichts zu tun ----> Ich habe sowieso, ohnehin nichts zu tun --->
colloquially ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The words *eh* and *eher* share their origin

> mittelhochdeutsch ē(r), althochdeutsch ēr, ursprünglich komparativisches Adverb zu einem Positiv mit der Bedeutung »früh« (vgl. gotisch air = früh) <sup>[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eher)</sup>

So, the word *ēr*, which does not exist anymore, means *früh* (*early*). This sense is still enclosed in the primary meaning of *eher*, namely *at an earlier date*. The other meanings of *eher* can chiefly be translated to *rather* or *quite*.

Regarding your second question the ultimate answer is 'No'. *Eh* is no abbreviation for *eher* and, furthermore, fulfills a completely different function. Its usage is colloquial, in the sense of *anyway*. For that reason, you can translate that sentence like this:

> There's nothing to do, anyway.

Without any context, however, it's hard to say if you should use *eh* or *eher*. I could think of a couple of situations where this sentence is fine with *eher* although the sentence will likely be slightly modified.

> War dein Tag anstrengend? Hast du alle Aufgaben erledigt bekommen?
>
> Ne, alles kein Problem. Ich hatte heute eher nichts zu machen.

Answer (score 6):

No. I would like to think that the "eh" here means "ohnehin". That is:

"Ich habe eh nichts zu tun." `<->` "Ich habe ohnehin nichts zu tun."

Comment: eh = ohnehin. That is a good start. I am looking for more information. Why is it ohnehin? How does one come from ohnehin > eh? To be fair, I changed the question and gave you 1+.

Comment: Sorry. I see the tag. I don't have any clue where it comes from.

Answer (score 4):

No:

`eher` means `a trend / tendency to`

`eh` means `anyway`

Comment: You have defined them. I already know the definitions. I am looking for reasons for their definitions. In many cases, words develop from other words. To be fair, I changed the question and gave you 1+.

Comment: okey, unfortunatly i dont know where this comes from, its just there, and i guess it isnt really necessary to know the etymology ;)

Comment: @Postback kann man "eh" immer durch "sowieso" ersetzen?

Comment: @RomanT, ja prinzipiell schon. Mir fällt spontan kein Fall ein indem dies nicht möglich wäre