# How do I say "anyway" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How do I say "anyway" in German? I wanna say it in this context:

> A: Lass uns morgen an den Strand gehen und viel Spass haben!
>
> B: Ja, wir können meine Schwester und ihre Freunde einladen, ja?
>
> A: (schaut sich über ihre Schulter zum Musikladen, wo die Leute hineingehen und herauskommen.) Wie auch immer, ja, könnnen wir.

Can "eh" be used in replacement for "Wie auch immer"?

Comment: Neither work in this context, do you mind giving an English version of what you mean?

Btw couple of amendments: "und ihre Freunde einladen, *oder*?".
and
I would prefer u. written as und. "u." is the equivalent of writing an ampersand (&). And hinein/heraus could be written with "*und*" in the middle instead of a /.

Comment: Translation :  Let's go to the beach and have fun! Can we invite my sister and her friends? Anyway, yes, we can.

Comment: So I take it there is a hefty gap between the line "B" says and when A says "anyway?". That's the only way that makes sense to me, as a way to return to the conversation.

Comment: @DerPolyglott33, please edit your question (using the "edit" link on its bottom right) and add the dialog in english (most important) with your suggested translation included. From what you've been saying so far, it is really hard to derive the actual context (or rather, from what I've gathered, using `anyway` is even bad/wrong in english)

Comment: I'll change the story :) Ich habe ein Haus in der Voltesstraße gesehen. Es hat vier Schlafzimmer und drei Badezimmer. Wie auch immer, es ist ein sehr schönes Haus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the one you're looking for is

> Auf jeden Fall /In jedem Fall

or

> definitiv - Es ist definitiv ein schönes Haus

*Wie auch immer* has too much of a notion of closing a discussion, which did not happen in your examples. *Eh* has nothing to do with these situations and it is not a synonym for *wie auch immer*. In English it as one certain kind of *anyway* but it can't stand alone.

[What is the etymology of "eh" in "Ich habe eh nichts zu machen"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6752/what-is-the-etymology-of-eh-in-ich-habe-eh-nichts-zu-machen)

Comment: I don't quite agree. "Das Haus hat vier Schlafzimmer und drei Badezimmer. (Das ist übertrieben, braucht ja kein Mensch. *oder* Das ist eine eigentlich unwichtige Randnotiz, die ich aber interessant fand.) Wie auch immer, es ist ein sehr schönes Haus" - Ja, das Problem besteht hier in der unvollständigen Frage. Am besten antwortet man da nicht. Ich vote jetzt für close.

Comment: @Em1... ich hatte auch Probleme, die Beispiele zu verstehen, aber es gibt im (Amerikanischen) English eine Verwendung von "anyway" die zumindest auf das zweite Beispiel passt "He was a demi god on the piano. A good player anyway."... und hier passt "auf jeden Fall" aber "wie auch immer" nicht so wirklich